# Can I apply infix function within the own class without `this`?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, we have infix

e.g. when we have

```
fun Int.test(value: Int) {}
```

We can use

```
1.test(2)
```

And when we put infix

```
infix fun Int.test(value: Int) {}
```

We can use as

```
1 test 2
```

For a class, the below is okay

```
class myclass {
    fun main() {
        test(1)
    }
    fun test(value: Int) {}
}
```

But with infix the below is not okay

```
class myclass {
    fun main() {
        test 1
    }
    infix fun test(value: Int) {}
}
```

Apparently, it has to have

```
class myclass {
    fun main() {
        this test 1
    }
    infix fun test(value: Int) {}
}
```

Can I omit `this`, since `test` is call within the class itself?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976405/infix-notation-and-with-does-not-work-as-i-expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infix notation and with(...) does not work as I expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976405/infix-notation-and-with-does-not-work-as-i-expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be omitted, you always need a left operand when using `infix` functions, which is `this` in your case:

"`receiver functionName parameter`"

There's no way around it.

Comment: I'm sad that this can't happen as a context of the infix function.  Very sad.